# circuit breaker for high avalability in microservices architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices, high-availability, circuit-breaker

I am trying to learn about Circuit breaker that ensures high availability of the services. I am new to it. Can somebody explain me what actually it is and how can I use to have avalability in the system. I see lot of arctiles for the same but I am not clear about. I want to implement it basically to have high avalability in the system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good read - https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html :)